# Connecting my new SB6121 modem to my Linksys E1200 router

Tags: wireless-router, internet-connection, modem

Yesterday, I purchased a new SB6121 modem to replace the one I was renting from Comcast. I called Comcast to activate the new modem and the Internet works but not wirelessly.

I've tried connecting the Ethernet cable from my modem to my router and that didn't work. I also tried connecting the router to my laptop to set up a new network. Problem is, it finds the old network through my Ethernet connection.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are power cycling the equipment between switching connection. Cable Modems typically do not like the connected MAC addresses changing. I'd recommend unplugging both from power, connecting them, connecting the cable to the modem, then applying power the router before applying power the modem. See if that works.